# Usage of weird symbol in haskell code

Tags: haskell

I came across on following code:

```
data Nested a = a :<: (Nested [a]) | Epsilon

mylength Epsilon    = 0
mylength (_ :<: xs) = 1 + mylength xs
```

What does `a :<: (Nested [a])` mean? I don't understand such code (especially `:<:`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:<:` is a data constructor, like `Just`. The only difference is that it is infix because it is symbolic. Infix data constructors must start with a `:`.

You could rewrite the above as:

```
data Nested a = Nest a (Nested [a]) | Epsilon

mylength Epsilon    = 0
mylength (Nest _ xs) = 1 + mylength xs
```

Comment: Great thanks. I did not know about such syntax